# Triple integral with a cone as a domain

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, solution-verification

How can I find $\displaystyle\iiint_D f$ if $f(x,y,z) =\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ $D$ is what is inside of $z^2=x^2+y^2,z=0,z=1$?.

I tried to do it with cylindrical coordinates as follows:

$x=\rho\cos\theta, y=\rho\sin\theta,z=z$; considering the condition $z^2=x^2+y^2$ I have that $\rho^2\cos^2\theta+\rho^2\sin^2\theta=z^2\implies\rho^2=z^2$, $\rho$ is always greater than zero, then $0\leq \rho\leq 1$ and it seems that I need to go the full circle then all the conditions are:

$$0\leq\rho \leq 1 \\ 0\leq\theta\leq 2\pi \\ 0 \leq z \leq 1$$

Then $$\iiint_Df(x,y,z)\;dxdydz = \int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 \sqrt{r^2}r\;drd\theta dz =\frac{1}{3}\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta dz = \frac{2}{3}\pi$$.

Is that right?. I've read that this also can be computed considering spherical coordinates, is there a good reason to use that change or just will make things harder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I've updated the post to the correct calculation of the cone. See below.

Using cylindrical coordinates you just missed one limit: it should be $z=r$ on the lower limit and $z=1$ for the upper. The computation is as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
\iiint\limits_{D} f \, dV & = \int_0^{2 \pi} \hspace{-5pt} \int_0^1 \hspace{-5pt} \int_r^1 r \cdot r \, dz \, dr \, d \theta \\
 & = 2 \pi \int_0^1 r^2 - r^3 \, dr \\
 & = 2 \pi \left( \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} \right) \\
 & = 2 \pi \cdot \frac{1}{12} \\
 & = \frac{\pi}{6}.
\end{align}
$$

I'm still taking sometime to figure out spherical coordinates. Sorry!

Comment: @Dante I've fixed it now. Can you check and comment?

Comment: Could you explain further how you figure out the limits for $z$?. I thought that considering $x^2+y^2=z^2$ the limits would be $0<z<r$ since the domain seems a cone pointing to the origin.
Thanks :)

Comment: I thought that at first too, but the problem is that those limits do not define the volume of the cone, but rather the volume outside it and inside the cylinder with unit radius and unit height. :) Another equivalent way of doing it would be to consider the cone upside down, that is, with the apex at $z=1$. The limits would be $0 \leq z \leq 1-r$ and the value will be the same.